# Adding placholder attribute to Magento CMS page

Tags: html, magento, placeholder

I am having trouble to add the placeholder attribute to the input elements in a CMS page of Magento. Something like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Hello" />
```

I proceed to save the CMS page, however, it seems to me that Magento overrides the placeholder attribute, preventing the placeholders normally seen in HTML from being displayed.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one's a little tricky.  If you check your `cms_page` database table, you'll find Magento is actually saving your HTML tag with a `placeholder` attribute.  Also, if you view the page via the frontend and not the admin interface, you'll find Magento renders your placeholder attribute.

The problem is, Magento's tinymce editor is configured to strip out invalid `input` attributes, and this list hasn't been updated to reflect changes in HTML5.

If you're using a reasonably modern version of Magento, you can fix this by inserting the following javascript into the admin page **after** the tinymce javascript is loaded, but **before** magento runs the inline `wysiwygpage_content = new tinyMceWysiwygSetup...` javascript.  **Warning:**  I just threw this together, it may not work in all browsers.  Buyer beware, test, etc.

```
if(tinyMceWysiwygSetup)
{
    tinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype.originalGetSettings = tinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype.getSettings;
    tinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype.getSettings = function(mode)
    {
        var settings = this.originalGetSettings(mode);
        settings.extended_valid_elements = 'input[placeholder|accept|alt|checked|disabled|maxlength|name|readonly|size|src|type|value]';
        return settings;
    }
}
```

**Update**: I have a [new module](https://github.com/astorm/MagentoTinyMCEConfig)  which provides an easy mechanism for adding these sorts of TinyMCE settings to Magento's editor.

Comment: Hey Alan. Thanks for the answer. I thought I was seeing things when I was trying to apply the placeholders.

Comment: @Alan Storm, could you please have a quick look at my struggle at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/324248/magento-2-3-why-do-html-tags-manually-added-in-magento-content-editor-for-an-cm